# Do Bike stores allow you to ship a bike to them to assemble?

Tags: shopping, new-bicycle-assembly

I live in Orlando, Florida, and I am stuck with no transportation besides public buses, taxis, etc. as my bike literally fell apart in pieces in the middle of a road. I am looking to purchase a new bike, but I would need for it to be professionally assembled. My question is would most bike shops work something out where I could ship it directly to them for assembly, so that I do not have to walk with a bike box for a few miles.

Comment: If you want to buy an assembled bike then why not just  buy an assembled bike from a bike shop?

Comment: local bike shop bikes are unfortunately not in my budget

Comment: And pay a bike store to assemble a bike you paid for single shipping is in your budget?  You have economics way messed up - a bike store can buy a bike less for than you can and they are going to charge retail for assembly.  Go to Wally Mart and buy a BSO or buy a used bike on like CL.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Ashley. I'm sure you could negotiate such a deal, but it would probably not be economic for you because the shop has its own priorities / focus / specialty. A better plan would be to ask them what bike they could get for you that would be in your budget. They may still not go for that and may offer you a used bike instead. See the **Related** questions listed at the right for the benefits of buying from a shop.

Comment: Where I worked we had a flat $100 fee to look at a bike bought off the internet or from Kmart/Target/Walmart etc. And an extra $100-$200 to assemble one, with the caveat that there was no warranty on anything other than the assembly. Too many of those bike *cannot* be assembled into something that's safe to ride. We know, we ordered a lot looking for a sub-$500 bike to stock (in Australia goods must be "of a merchantable quality and fit for purpose", so they cost more than in the USA).

Comment: By the time you buy a basic bike, get it shipped and get it assembled, you'll be able to afford a basic bike from the shop (e.g. a Trek 7.0 fx). Try other shops if one is too expensive, and look for used bikes.

Comment: You might try to find a bike mechanic that can come to you. If you're buying a bikesdirect type bike it's not very hard to assemble, but you'd still want a decent mechanic to do it. (FWIW I find bikesdirect bikes to be a good deal. The wheels, tires, seat and pedals are usually substandard but good enough start you off and can be replaced later.)

Comment: Related - Bike shops are normally happy to pack a bike and courier it at your cost.  Do shop around though, I had quotes from $240 down to $80 for the same bike, which was a folder so no spannerwork required.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are two questions here:

**1 - Can you have a bike professionally assembled by a bike shop?**  In my experience (having done this a couple of times) it will typically cost the price of their "pro tune" or equivalent - the service when they break the bike down and put it back together.  $2-300 say.  Bike shops can be a bit sniffy about this, but getting to know your local tech staff will help make things easier.

**2 - Is this a good idea?**  Depends why you're doing it.  If you've got a frame or components you want to put together - say you bought a particular rare steel frame that you want your gruppo from your other bike on...then it can be a great option.  If it's about buying a high-end bike for cheaper - it *may* be a good option but check where you're sourcing from. If it's about buying a cheaper (say sub $500) bike for less than you can pay in an LBS - I'd say a crazy false economy.  Instead, buy a second hand bike on CL or similar and save $100 or so to get it checked out by your LBS.

Slightly aligned to the point above - if I'm a bike mech, being asked to work on a cool steel frame or a high-end bike from a brand I may never have worked on is pretty cool.  Being asked to spanner a cheap bike from Walmart is going to make me feel pretty crappy about myself and question why I work in the industry.  The level of work I do is likely to be commensurate with how the work makes me feel...

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, bike shops don't make much money off of turning wrenches. It then follows that they don't typically care for some bike that you chose to buy online instead of from their showroom, which is where most of their money is made. If you buy something that doesn't align well with a particular shop, i.e. an overly cheap bike and a shop that deals a lot with higher-end stuff, they might not want to associate themselves with such an inferior product. Cheap shifters and derailleurs, for example, can be impossible to dial in. One can not expect even a seasoned mechanic to be responsible for cheap metals that bend under pressure as their eventual imperfect performance could then be associated with his work or his shop. As a second example, cheaper rims can be a nightmare to true; as is expecting them to remain so. The time that it takes to work with a cheap bike is not worth the shop's time. All of this being said, however, just go into the bike shop and explain your situation to them. If you're ordering something that they think is worth their time, then expect to pay at least $100 to $125 for them to properly assemble it and tune it. They might even be able to show you something there in the shop that is comparable to what you're interested in!

Answer (score 3):

My local bike shop has a posted price of $80 to assemble a bike as received in a box (presumably bought over the internet) and $200 to assemble a bike from a frame and set of components.  One of my friends bought a frame and groupset (quite a nice one) and they were happy to do the work.  You should talk to the specific shop you are thinking of and see what they say. The same shop has free lifetime adjustments on any bike you buy from them, so you need to figure that into your calculation of the economics.

Answer (score 2):

Yes many bicycle repair shops offer assembly service.  Of course they would also like a shot at your business for the bike.  You will generally get more free service from a shop where you purchased the bike, so there is some value to that.

Answer (score 2):

I just called a couple of local shops about assembly, one was very straightforward and easy to talk with and gave a simple price. One was like these guys above, a lot of double talk nonsense. I'm going with the straightforward. Assembly is pretty simple. The answer should be too. 
There are many good online bike sellers and the box arrives needing assembly. 
I called a shop near me as i am in the same situation with public transport.
Perhaps you could call your local shops and ask if you could have it delivered to them for assembly. Best wishes fellow foot, bike and pub trans commuter.

Comment: Welcome to bicycles.SE!  We recommend that all new users take [the tour](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) to get the most from the site.